# Does ID function create a new object?

Tags: python

I have 2 variables (links) a and b that are pointing to the same object, and, of course

```
a is b #true
```

But when im asking about memory addr for the same object that this links pointing to

```
id(a) is id(b) #false
```

Does that mean that id is creating a new object ? How long will this object last ? What type will it be? What's going on?

Comment: id returns an integer. Use `==` to compare integers, not `is`.

Comment: You can also refer to the Python documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id

Comment: So id returning int, and this int is stored as int object...but what happens to the link of this new object ?

Comment: What im trying to say is - basically id(a) has to store this data somewhere in memory right ? so py must create a new object with int type(ty), link, gc data and this int. What will happen with the link?

Comment: The `int` object returned by `id()` will last exactly as long as anything has a reference to it - *exactly like every other object in Python*.

Comment: @jasonharper id(a) is id(b) - here..i don't really understand the reference part. When id(a) is called will it create a reference by itself ?

Comment: `id()` will return a reference - because no other possibility exists for Python functions.  Whether that reference is to an existing `int` object, or a brand-new `int` object, is not something you should ever need to care about - but in practice, it will almost certainly be a new object in this particular situation.  Therefore the `is` test produces False, even though the two int objects have the same numeric value.

Comment: @jasonharper, ok, i get it, but when for example we are doing something like a = id(b) this new int object will have a as it's reference, but if we are just calling id(a) what reference will this object get. When we are calling a function without any variable assignment will this new created object has some sort of None or False as data in refference field and dissapear immediately ?

Comment: Variables aren't the only form of reference - a function call in progress temporarily holds references to all of the parameters (so they cannot disappear in the middle of the call), a list holds references to all of its elements, etc.  Note that an object has no knowledge about *what* is referencing it, it only has a count of references (which triggers deletion when it goes to zero).

Comment: @jasonharper, so this id(a) object is created with ref count as 1, after the call it becomes 0 and object goes to a better place ? If function is being called the ref part in object that was created equal to 1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> a is b
True
```

They are the same object...

```
>>> id(a) == id(b)
True
```

They have the same id...

```
>>> id(a) is id(b)
False
```

...but the `int`egers representing their `id`s are not the same object.

That's because in Python `int`s are `object`s too.

---

I would suggest you to read [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is), [`this`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) and [`this`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int).

Comment: Yeah, this is basically an answer. Ty FLAK-ZOSO and @jasonharper, now i just have to wrap my head around reference creation part..

Comment: You'll probably want to read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html as well.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the following answer will get very wordy but hopefully lucid enough... If any clarification is required please let me know.

In the first statement `a is b`, you are basically **comparing the address of the two objects** (or pointers/references to the same object). So you are asking if `a` is the same as `b`, and you get True.

But in the second statement `id(a) is id(b)` you aren't comparing the addresses of `a` and `b`. You are **comparing the address of the two objects that are holding the value of the addresses of `a` and `b`**.

Still confused? Let's see an example..

```
a = [1]
b = a
a is b      #True
```

The reason for the above output: `a` and `b` are pointing to the same list object

```
address1 = id(a)
address2 = id(b)
address1 is address2      #False
```

The reason for the above output: `address1` and `address2` are integers and while they contain the same value, those values are stored in different objects. Similarly when you run `id(a) is id(b)`, you are **comparing the two different address-value-holding objects and not the object addresses**.

SOLUTION:

Just type,

```
id(a) == id(b) # This will tell you whether the location of a and b is the same. 
#If the output is true, then a and b point to the same object.
```

Hope that makes things clearer!